# Кэш input после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, кэширование

Подскажите есть возможность после перезагрузки страницы повторно использовать значение поля input? т.е. своего рода кэш (cookie) поля (input)? чтобы после перезагрузки пользователь, который вводил значение в поле, снова увидел бы в поле это же самое значение в этом же поле. Есть идеи по данной реализации?

Comment: Идеи есть. Можно использовать своего рода кэш (cookie) или `localStorage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jquery cookie](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie)

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
   $.cookie('input_' + $(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
});

...

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').each(function(){
      $(this).val($.cookie('input_' + $(this).attr('name')));
   })
});
```

Comment: Потрясно, спасибо :))